# Handle AJAX response with Remotipart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, file-upload

I am using [Remotipart](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart) to upload images via AJAX in a Rails project. The image upload is handled by the rails controller and works fine.

But the form is a *multi-step* form, and image upload is just the first of the steps. After uploading the image it's rendered in the view and what I need is that after that, go to the next step if the image was uploaded, but can't figure out how to do it. Can't even make work this awaiting an AJAX response:

```
$(document).ready (e) ->
  $("form").bind "ajax:complete", (e, data, status, error) ->
    if data.status is 200 or data.status is 201
      alert 'yum'
```

My controller looks like:

```
def upload
  if request.post?
    dir = "/img/" + current_user.slug + "/pictures/queue/"
    ndir = dir + view_context.random_s(10) + '.jpg'
    File.rename(params[:file].tempfile, "public" + ndir)
    render :text => "$('#picture #photo').html('<img src=\"#{ndir}\">');"
  end
end
```

But how I said this part works great.

I think it could be possible doing it by just adding an event handler to the form or just using `render :text` in the controller, but that wouldn't be a nice thing.

I have seen some answer on SO about this, but no one works.